# How to run interactive script inside the docker

Tags: docker

I want to run an interactive script inside the docker container. I have created the image which contains the interactive script. I want to run that script when I am launching the image inside the docker container. But its not running.

Can Someone please help me or share a link for that. My need is when I launch the container that script should hit and from the container it should communicate and ask for the input.

Comment: How are you launching your container ? exact command please

Comment: sudo docker run -it <image-name> bash -c "<your-script-full-path>; bash"

Comment: Can you share example of relevant sections of your Dockerfile as well?

Comment: Its not launching.

Comment: This is the command by which i am invoking the script
CMD ["/opt/ibm-ucd-agent-install/install-agent.sh"]
I tried this with Entrypoint.sh also but its not working.
The script which I am trying to invoke its agent.sh. and its the shell script which is running fine in local but inside docker how to run it?

Comment: Do the user supposed to start the script have execute permission?

Comment: Well it is hard to say without rest of your Dockerfile and entrypoint, used image etc... But for shot in the dark, did you try to build with `CMD /opt/ibm-ucd-agent-install/install-agent.sh`?

Comment: Can you give me any link or example where interactive script is running inside the docker container. My requirement is when I run the image inside the container one script should invoked which ask for entering the data from the user.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution:

First the script which prompts the user: input.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo who are you?
read someone
echo hello $someone
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM bash:4 
COPY ./input.sh input.sh
RUN chmod +x input.sh
CMD ./input.sh
```

Just build it

```
docker build -t testinput .
```

And run it:

```
docker run -i testinput:latest
```

The output:

```
$ docker run -i testinput:latest 
who are you?
bob
hello bob
```

The important part is the `-i` option that runs the container interactively